# Various model number styles of MacbookPro

Tags: macbook-pro

On the bottom of my MacbookPro the model number is **A1707**.  But when I go to system report via the apple menu, it lists the model identifier as **MacBookPro13,3**.  Are these just synonyms for the same thing?  Or do they signify some different aspects of the equipment.

More importantly, which one should I use to search replacement parts for my laptop?

Comment: Both, depends on parts and supplier.

Comment: The model number is next to useless. You found one of the few examples that only refers to a limited number of actually similar models. Some model numbers cover years, of vastly different Macs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same thing to Apple, Both identify the type and year but not the actual specs.
If you want to search for specific parts you need to search to include screen size, year and the CPU details then either MacBookPro13,3 or A1707.

Because there are 3 different macbooks that are identified as "MacBookPro13,3" and "A1707" so you it should look like this
Eg: "MacBook Pro 15-Inch "Core i7" 2.9 Touch/Late 2016"

All those details are in System Information

Comment: So if model number doesn't uniquely identify the model, what's the point?  And why have two of seemingly useless unidentifying model numbers?

Comment: You'd have to ask Apple. The "MacBookPro13,1" is the Model Identifier and the "A1707" is the Model#. Which are basically the same but I think they have both because there maybe products that have the same "Model#" but are from a different product line, so to specify they need the "Model Identifier" as well.